# p-adic valuation for multinomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Kummer's formula
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Kummer%27s_theorem&oldid=745783657
says that
$$
  \text{ord}_p \binom{n}{k}
$$
is the number of carries required when adding the base-$p$ expansions
of $k$ and $n-k$. Is there a similar formula for the $p$-adic
valuation of a multinomial coefficient
$$
  \binom{n}{k_1,\ldots,k_r} := \frac{n!}{k_1!\cdots k_r!} ?
$$
If so, is there a good reference (free online for preference, but failing that,
in a book)?

There is a related question
[Reference needed for Lucas' Theorem for multinomial coefficients modulo a prime](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80169/reference-needed-for-lucas-theorem-for-multinomial-coefficients-modulo-a-prime),
but it involves the *value* of the multinomial coefficient modulo $p$, not the *$p$-adic valuation*.

Comment: Isn't it just going to be the total number of carries required when first adding $k_1$ and $k_2$, then adding $k_1+k_2$ and $k_3$, then adding $k_1+k_2+k_3$ and $k_4$, etc.?

Comment: Tom's argument also shows the total number of carries does not depend on the order of summation. If one asked me to prove that last statement, I don't know how one would start without having Joe's question in mind.

Comment: If I had to prove the statement  @Abdelmalek made regarding order of summation, I would use induction on the number of summands, making sure I did the case of three summands carefully.  Gerhard "Is Feeling Rather Recursiony Today" Paseman, 2017.03.28.

Comment: @Gerhard: maybe with general Witt vectors?

Comment: @Abdelmalek , sorry, have not knowingly worked with Witt vectors.  I would prove that the total number of carries is independent of summand order in much the same way I would prove the total is independent of summand order.  Gerhard "Isn't Fond Of Mathematical Machinery" Paseman, 2017.03.28.

Comment: Yes, this is just the total carry. Reminds me of the following result due to Steve Doty: When we view the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in $r$ variables as a module over $SL_r(\overline{\Bbb{F}_p})$, acting on the variables by linear substitutions, the various *carry patters* (=which carrys appear at which digit positions) determines the irreducible composition factors. Yours truly had the pleasure of extending and refining (to the extent it was feasible) those results to algebraic groups of types $B,C,D$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Denote the sum of the digits of $n$ in base $b$ by $S(n)$. Then the number of carries when adding $k_1+k_2$ is 
$$\frac{1}{b-1}\big(S(k_1)+S(k_2)-S(k_1+k_2)\big).$$
This shows that the number of carries when successively adding $(((k_1+k_2)+k_3)+\cdots +k_r)$ is
$$\frac{1}{b-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^r S(k_i)-S\left(\sum_{i=1}^r k_i\right)\right),$$
and this last expression is clearly independent of the order in which they are added. The formula for the multinomial coefficient can thus be written as
$$\operatorname{ord}_p \binom{n}{k_1,\ldots,k_r}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^rS(k_i)-S(n)}{p-1}.$$

Comment: Nice! Do you know analogues of Kummer's formula for more exotic integer-valued ratios of factorials as in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26336/integer-valued-factorial-ratios ? meaning a relation between order in $p$ and carries when doing arithmetic with arguments of the factorials.

Comment: Using the formula ${\rm ord}_p(n!) = (n - S(n))/(p-1)$, your last formula follows from taking the $p$-adic valuation of each factorial appearing in the multinomial coefficient: $(n - S(n))/(p-1) - \sum_{i=1}^r (k_i - S(k_i))/(p-1)$: since $n = k_1 + \cdots + k_r$, in that difference the $n$ and $\sum k_i$ cancel out. Also it shows the order of subtraction in your formula is backwards: it should be $(\sum_{i=1}^r S(k_i) - S(n))/(p-1)$.

Comment: @KConrad Thank you! It was backwards, and it's fixed now.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi I hope you won't mind that I added this formula to the Wikipedia page on Kummer's theorem.

Answer (score 6):

You can write:

$$\binom{n}{k_1,\ldots,k_r} = \frac{n!}{k_1!\cdots k_r!}$$

as:

$$\binom{n}{k_1,\ldots,k_r} = \binom{n}{k_1}\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}\ldots\binom{n-k_1\ldots-k_{r-1}}{k_r}$$

Comment: What does this have to do with the question being asked about p-adic valuations?

Comment: @YemonChoi; apply $ord_p$ to each component on the RHS

Comment: this is basically the idea given by Tom in a comment above.